# angular 2: view.setLocal('\$implicit', change.item); deprecated with what?

Tags: angular

`angular 2: view.setLocal('\$implicit', change.item);`

used to work but removed with rc.1
any ideas with what as trying to get this working:

http://teropa.info/blog/2016/03/06/writing-an-angular-2-template-directive.html

```
ngDoCheck():void {
        if (this.differ) {
            let changes = this.differ.diff(this.items);
            if (changes) {
                console.log('template', this.template);
                changes.forEachAddedItem((change) => {
                    let view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
                    //todo: fix as broken in rc.1
                    //view.setLocal('\$implicit', change.item);
                    this.views.set(change.item, view);
                });
                changes.forEachRemovedItem((change) => {
                    let view = this.views.get(change.item);
                    let idx = this.viewContainer.indexOf(view);
                    this.viewContainer.remove(idx);
                    this.views.delete(change.item);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

how would you change the setLocal to the new version of set context?
regards

Sean

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to do: 

`view.context.$implicit = change.item;
this.views.set(change.item, view);`

Comment: Isn't `context` read only as per documentation?https://angular.io/api/core/EmbeddedViewRef#context

Answer (score 2):

`EmbeddedViewRef.setLocal` and `getLocal` have been removed.

Use `EmbeddedViewRef.context` to access the context.

Comment: can you help with the snippet? I have updated my question with the code